# How to get started in Firefox extension development

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am new to Firefox extension development. What languages should I know, and what tools are required to be installed on my Windows machine?

Are there any good tutorials available for this?

Answer (score 5):

Since Firefox 4 you have the "choice of weapon": Traditionally, extensions are written in Javascript and embedded in [XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL). The new way still uses Javascript, but embeds the addon in classic HTML+CSS.

For XUL, there are good documents at [the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/addons) (start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension)). The newer techique is called Jetpack, [website](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/), and offers a Python-based [SDK (zip file)](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/jetpack/addon-sdk-latest.zip).

Answer (score 5):

I am using this a bit old but still perfect solution;

- Download Eclipse (I am using Helios - Eclipse IDE for Java EE
  Developers)
  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2
- Install WTP : Help > Install new software > work with: The Eclipse
  Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository -
  http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios
- Download XulBooster: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xulbooster/ (Yes
  a bit old but still works perfect)
- File > New > Other > Xul >Extension Project etc.This creates a simple .xpi for you.
- Dont forget adjust min and max version of firefox from install.rdf dependencies tab. From overview tab you can export your project by clicking "using the export wizard" link.

Sorry that is not detailed but you can figure it out easliy.

Comment: I did the steps (but the version is old and throws errors when updating). So I recommend to download the latest Eclipse version from the homepage called something like Java EE Developer. After installation install the Webtools from the default repo. After this you can use the http://eclipsexul.sourceforge.net/chapter-installation.html for accessing xul files. You won't have a managment for the manifest and install file - but there always line which have to handled manually.